# How to update unlimited form field form in database?

Tags: mysql, database, forms

My form structure is like this in which `fields[]` input can be added any number of times at time of submission of form.Here i am storing website link in `fields[]` .

```
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
<input id="field_1" name="fields[]" type="text" />
<input id="field_2" name="fields[]" type="text" />
<input id="field_3" name="fields[]" type="text" />
```

I have managed to store this data in a MySQL database using the table structure below to allow a user to be associated with an unlimited number of websites:

```
Users       User_website_link     Websites
------      -----------------     ---------
Pk:UserID   Pk:ID               Pk:WebsiteId
name        UserID              Url
            WebsiteID
```

Let say user fills following data in form {"Jon", "example.com", "example1.com", "example2.com" }

So after submitting form table would be looking like this:

**User table:**

```
UserID   Username
1         Jon
```

**Websites Table:**

```
WebsiteID      Url
1               example.com
2               example1.com
3               example3.com
```

**User_website_link Table:**

```
ID   UserID    WebsiteId
1     1         1
2     1         2
3     1         3
```

How should I allow the user to edit their URLs after submitting them?

So my question is: a user called John wants to delete `example3.com` and edit `example.com` to `demo.com`, So I want to know how to delete some websites from the database and edit some.

Comment: what do you exactly want? your question is quite unclear

Comment: from your use-case, can two users share the same website Url?

Comment: @codingbiz yes two users can have same URL that is why i have made user_website_link table.

Comment: @Rajul Are you expecting for lots of users to have the same URLs? If you aren't then it is probably both faster and less storage-space heavy to store the UserID alongside the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the user_website_link table - you can just put a UserID in another column in your websites table.

But to answer the question:

You do not need to edit entries, simply add another column that is something like boolean `is_deleted` and only display or use URLs that have the `is_deleted` as false. So you just let the user add an extra URL for editing, and just set the `is_deleted` when you delete them. Of course you could remove that row on deletion, or clear deleted ones later, but I think this method is slightly easier.

Comment: @Rajul You would do something like `INSERT INTO websites (url, userid) VALUES ($url, $userid)` (That probably does not work, and if it isn't what you wanted, just say.)

Answer (score 1):

Just like @bearbin said, with this structure none of the use owns the website, so if one edited it and the other does not want how would you tackle that. With your structure what you can only have is `insert` and `delete`.

To make the user owns the website, then your structure needs to change to

```
Websites(WebsiteID, URL, UserID)
```

where `UserID` is the foreign key. The `WebsiteID` will be unique to each user in this case.